# Modelling a numeric result against a change in percentage

Tags: javascript, numbers, calculation

I have a calculation which returns a percentage

`TotalDelegatedStake / circulatingSupply * 100 = Y%`

And I have a different calculation that also uses the first variable

```
let emissions = numberinput4.value;

let stake = numberinput2.value / TotalDelegatedStake;
let penalty = numberinput3.value <= 98.5 ? '0' : numberinput3.value / 100;
let fee = numberinput5.value == 0 ? 1 : 1 - (numberinput5.value / 100);

let calc = emissions * stake * penalty * fee;

return calc;
```

I would like to be able to model what the result of `calc` would be if `Y%` increased or decreased in value.

Eg. it's 30% now what would the result of `calc` be if it was 40%.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you further explain what you want to do? What is Y% is it emissions? Just add/ remove 10 from emissions and rerun the calculation so that you get the result

Comment: Y% is defined in this calculation 
`TotalDelegatedStake / circulatingSupply * 100 = Y%` 
and is a fluid value based on the variables 'TotalDelegatedStake' and 'circulatingSupply'

Comment: Y% is basically the ratio of those two variables. I want to calculate what the impact would be on the 2nd calculation if the ratio increased or decreased.